# How to get a list of RUs, SPs and other updates installed for Exchange from a command line or PowerShell?

Tags: exchange, powershell, windows-command-prompt

Is there a way to get a list of updates, rollups, service packs **installed for the MS Exchange Server** from a command line, PowerShell or Exchange Management Shell?

I already tried `Get-Hotfix`, `Get-WmiObject` and `Systeminfo` but all of the above seem to return lists of updates installed only for the system (Windows) and not for the Exchange.

Edit: `Get-ExchangeServer` does not satisfy my needs as for Exchange 2010 SP3 it seems to always report Build version 123.4 despite all newer Rollups installed and real build number being 224.2.

[image: Get-ExchangeServer results vs list of installed updates for Exchange]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The Microsoft-recommended way](http://blogs.technet.com/b/rmilne/archive/2013/10/29/how-to-check-exchange-2010-ru-version.aspx) of getting your Exchange service pack and rollup version is to get the file version info on `Exsetup.exe`.

In the Exchange Management Shell, use:

> Get-Command  Exsetup.exe | ForEach-Object {$_.FileversionInfo}

And then look up the version returned against Microsoft's [`Exchange Server Updates: build numbers and release dates`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh135098%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx) page.

And yeah, that's really as granular as you can get, unless you want to parse a list of all installed updates for Exchange-specific updates.

Comment: Awesome, this seems to work.